# PHP, BDD with Behat and Mink (Selenium2 driver): How to close the browser window at the end of the test programatically?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, bdd, behat, mink

I am trying to learn **BDD** in PHP with [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/) and [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/) and I am using [Selenium2 driver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/selenium2.html) for the same.

**My question** is once the tests are over, how to programmatically close each browser window/tab that Selenium2 opens? Since closing so many browser windows/tabs each time after each test is time consuming.

I see there are some options out there that allow to do the same in Java, the native language of Selenium2 (I am also using the .jar file), but in PHP I could not find the equivalent.

---

**Note:**

For more information, I have included the code that I am trying.

I am trying to write `FeatureContext.php` for `example.feature` on [this page](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html), that is:

```
# features/search.feature
Feature: Search
    In order to see a word definition
    As a website user
    I need to be able to search for a word

    Scenario: Searching for a page that does exist
        Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
        When I fill in "search" with "Behavior Driven Development"
        And I press "searchButton"
        Then I should see "agile software development"

    Scenario: Searching for a page that does NOT exist
        Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
        When I fill in "search" with "Glory Driven Development"
        And I press "searchButton"
        Then I should see "Search results"
```

My `FeatureContext.php` is as follows:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

/**
* Defines application features from the specific context.
*/
class FeatureContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
    * Initializes context.
    *
    * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
    * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
    * context constructor through behat.yml.
    */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver('firefox');
        $this->session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($this->driver);        
        $this->session->start();
    }


    /**
    * @Given I am on :url
    */
    public function iAmOn($url)
    {
        $this->session->visit('http://en.wikipedia.org'.$url);
    }

    /**
    * @When I fill in :field with :text
    */
    public function iFillInWith($field, $text)
    {
        $this
            ->session
            ->getPage()
            ->find('css', '[type=' . $field . ']')
            ->setValue($text);
    }

    /**
    * @When I press :button
    */
    public function iPress($button)
    {
        $this
            ->session
            ->getPage()
            ->find('css', '[id=' . $button . ']')
            ->press();
    }

    /**
    * @Then I should see :text
    */
    public function iShouldSee($text)
    {
        $title = $this
            ->session
            ->getPage()
            ->find('css', 'h1')
            ->getText();

        if ($title !== $text) {
            new Exception('Invalid page');
        }
        $this->driver->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
/**
* @AfterScenario
*/
public function tearDown()
{
    $this->session->stop();
}
```